# JSON.parse works but jQuery.getJSON returns http error 403

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

When I use JSON.parse(jsonString), the JSON is parsed no problem at all.

```
var result = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

But when I use jQuery.getJSON(jsonString) i received an http error 403.

```
var result = jQuery.getJSON(jsonString);
```

Any idea why one will work and the other will not? They are both reading a string.

Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation for [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)... it doesn't read a string, it makes a request to a server and tries to parse the response as JSON

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> They are both reading a string.

Oh no! Those two methods are so very much different. They have absolutely nothing in common. They are accomplishing 2 entirely different tasks.

The first simply parses a JSON string into a javascript object:

```
var result = JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}');
alert(result.foo);
```

will show `bar`. Also notice that the [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) method is a built-in method in modern browsers. It's pure javascript and has strictly nothing to do with jQuery. Legacy browsers do not support it. For them you need to include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

[The second](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) performs an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call and expects as argument an url:

```
jQuery.getJSON('/someserversidescript', function(result) {
    // callback to be executed when the AJAX request succeeds
});
```

As you can see here the argument is an url. Calling `jQuery.getJSON('{"foo": "bar"}')` makes strictly no sense. I guess that's the reason why your server responds with 403 error, since this is not valid url on your server. It expects that the server will return a JSON string as response. It's simply a shorthand for:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/someserversidescript',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        // callback to be executed when the AJAX request succeeds
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`getJSON()` is an asynchronous call back to a server that returns a JSON object. `JSON.parse()` takes a string and returns a JSON object in memory. They are completely different.